# dGrid table scroll horizontally programmatically

Tags: javascript, scroll, dojo, dgrid

Is there a method in dGrid which let's you scroll to a certain column in the table, I have a table which is scrollable horizontally and I want to know if there is possibility to do something like:

```
myGrid.scrollToColumn(someColumnToScrollTo);
```

I know I can scroll vertically to some row, is there anything similar for what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kfranqueiro (Dojo 1.x committer and dgrid maintainer) said here:

https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/360

> Firstly, there is a scrollTo method on dgrid instances, which you can
>   pass an object with x or y properties to scroll in a platform-agnostic
>   manner

still him, here he use that function:

https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/1279

> grid.scrollTo({ y: index * grid.get('rowHeight') })

you need to pass x instead of y and the offset you need instead of index * grid.get('rowHeight')

Comment: will try it and post back after